# How can I tell if I'm running in a VMWARE virtual machine (from linux)?

Tags: perl, vmware, redhat, esx

I have a VMWARE ESX server. I have Redhat VMs running on that server. I need a way of programatically testing if I'm running in a VM. Ideally, I'd like to know how to do this from Perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the answer to "[Detect virtualized OS from an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154163/detect-virtualized-os-from-an-application)".

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't 100% depend on any method, as they are undocumented features/bugs - they work on some host OSes and some virtualization solutions, but there is no guarantee that they will continue working; indeed, the whole point of virtualization is to be as undistinguishable from real metal as possible. With this in mind, the [blue pill red pill](http://www.invisiblethings.org/papers/redpill.html) (which is mentioned in the accepted answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154163/detect-virtualized-os-from-an-application)) seems to work ... for now.

Answer (score 3):

VMWare has a couple of SDK's, including an [SDK for Perl](http://vmware.com/download/sdk/).

Answer (score 2):

I think (depending on the version of esx) you can inspect at the MAC address of the NIC. VMs running in VMWare NIC will have a manufacturer string assigned to VMWare, no the physical NIC MAC. (We were trying to spoof the MAC to VM a license server and newer versions won't let you do it.) Also, this won't guarantee you aren't running on a physical box with a NIC spoofed to look like VMWare, but that would be an odd thing to do in most circumstances anyway.

Comment: Virtualbox lets you enter any MAC you want

Comment: I would assume that you can change it in ESX. It's a very useful feature if you are trying to run licenced apps in a VM

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command:

```
lspci | grep VMware
```

It should show something like this:

> 00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
>
> 00:11.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI bridge (rev 02)
>
> 00:15.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)

Comment: I see the VMware VGA controller even for VirtualBox (on Windows with Ubuntu guest).