# Detecting virtual machine in Java

Tags: java, types, virtual-machine, detection

I've been searching for a good way to detect whether the app is running in a virtual machine with a java application, so it can run on any virtualized OS. But all the links I've found are with different programming languages, most of which I don't have any expertise in.

I also need the app to detect in what Virtual Machine Software it is running.

I'm sure it's possible somehow but so far, no luck. I was wondering how much everyone else knows about this subject.

My goal is to have a java application that can observe student laptops during exams, so that any attempts to cheat with network connections can be observed. This app needs to know if it is running in a virtual machine so the students can't trick the teachers that way.

Comment: And how do you do that outside Java (JVM)?

Comment: Strictly speaking java apps always run inside a virtual machine: the JVM - java virtual machine. Maybe you can explain what you're trying to accomplish and why, so it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: Well, there are a lot of examples out there which use the Red Pill technique (of which all links to the source are broken), and also examples that check for the hardware adress name, that's almost always the same when in a virtual machine. But since that name says 'Microsoft Corperation' and the code wasn't in java, I assumed it only works for windows VM's.

Comment: hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154163/detect-virtualized-os-from-an-application

Comment: I've already found that link and it's quite outdated, and the links that go to the source are broken.

Comment: @Eric you need first to find a way to do it outside Java, then we will show you how to use it in Java. But I'm pretty sure it will be necessary to call native code

Comment: Awhile ago I started using JNA, and so far it offers quite some useful functionality.