# Detect Virtual Machine with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, virtual-machine

Is it possible to detect that I am running under Virtual Machine from the code of Action Script3 (or lower)?

I know there is Capabilities class that providers some info about the system, but it doesn't seem to fit my needs fully.

Perhaps there is no such a flag anywhere, but I can count on some indirect information to understand that environment is virtualized?

Regards,
Sergey.

Comment: Your question is incredibly vague (you give no reasons, so we can't possibly give you any workarounds), but have you tried [`Capabilities.isDebugger`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#isDebugger)?

Comment: Are your referring to the ActionScript Virtual Machine itself or the system running the AVM?

Comment: We suspect some of players of our online game are cheating, e.g automate user actions. If I can detect from AS3 that a user is running browser under Virtual Machine (VMWare, VirtualBox, Virtual PC etc.) - it can be a flag for us for futher investigation of the player actions.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that checking this would be easy, especially from such an isolated enviroment as browser plugin sandbox. Modern virtual machines can emulate everything very accurately down to CPU registers and it is often hard to detect a vm even when you can access regular OS APIs. And when running in a browser you don't even have that (with AIR, you could write a native extension). You can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154163/detect-virtualized-os-from-an-application) for some info that may prove useful.

Comment: Yes, you are right, browser has very limited permissions to access the OS API functions, but I know it provides some info about the system configuration it is running under. Maybe I use one of OS parameters provided by browser/flash engine and chech how "real" it is. For example for real OS the Capabilities.hasMultiChannelAudio parameter could be any, but for VM it is always "DTE" (it is just a guess). So, I am trying to find some flags that tell me that "most likely" the client is running under VM.