# import platform get os info

Tags: python, server

How can I create a python script to get a server information base on these fields?

```
hostname, osrelease, if it's a virtual or physical server.
```

Output

```
hostname1, redhat 5.8, VMware
```

I have something like this:

```
import platform

print 'uname:', platform.uname()

print 'system   :', platform.system()
print 'node     :', platform.node()
print 'release  :', platform.release()
```

Comment: Hi, can you share some code to show what you've tried so far? Thanks!

Comment: I have somthing like this as a code.:

I have something like this as a code.:

import platform

print 'uname:', platform.uname()

print 'system   :', platform.system()
print 'node     :', platform.node()
print 'release  :', platform.release()

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Is this script running on the server? What do you mean by hostname, the DNS entry corresponding to the IP-adres?

Comment: Yes the script is running on the server. The script will collect the information only.

Answer (score 0):

The first two columns of your required output are quite simple to obtain:

```
import platform
print (platform.node(), ' '.join(platform.dist()[:2]))
```

The information of the last column, i.e. if Python is running under a virtual or physical machine, seems tricky. Consult the following pages for some hints:

- [How one detects x86 virtual machines](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/detecting-x86-virtual-machines.html?_sm_au_=iVV5QTQ1k2R4tt6F)
- [Detect virtualized OS from an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154163/detect-virtualized-os-from-an-application)

Have a look also at the following modules:

- [pycpuid](https://github.com/FlightDataServices/PyCPUID)
- [cpuid](https://github.com/flababah/cpuid.py)
- [cpuidpy](https://code.google.com/p/cpuidpy/)

Comment: Thank you, for you help.. I really wanted to see see if the servers is "virtual or physical" using the the Python script not Python under either servers env. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.